# Raspberry Pi Upgrade Fails

Tags: raspberry-pi

When i tried to upgrade or update raspberry pi or python on raspberry pi, i got this error

```html
pi@raspberry:/$ sudo apt-get install python
sudo: unable to resolve host raspberry: Name or service not known
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ***
Suggested packages:
  ***
0 upgraded, 101 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,560 kB/33.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 104 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libpython2.7-minimal armhf 2.7.16-2+deb10u1 [395 kB]
Get:2 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python2.7-minimal armhf 2.7.16-2+deb10u1 [1,091 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python2-minimal armhf 2.7.16-1 [41.4 kB]
Get:4 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python-minimal armhf 2.7.16-1 [21.0 kB]
Get:5 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf mime-support all 3.62 [37.2 kB]
Get:6 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libexpat1 armhf 2.2.6-2+deb10u1 [77.3 kB]
Get:7 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libpython2.7-stdlib armhf 2.7.16-2+deb10u1 [1,844 kB]
Get:8 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python2.7 armhf 2.7.16-2+deb10u1 [305 kB]
Get:9 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libpython2-stdlib armhf 2.7.16-1 [20.8 kB]
Get:10 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libpython-stdlib armhf 2.7.16-1 [20.8 kB]
Get:11 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python2 armhf 2.7.16-1 [41.6 kB]
Get:12 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf python armhf 2.7.16-1 [22.8 kB]
Get:13 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf bzip2 armhf 1.0.6-9.2~deb10u1 [46.2 kB]
Get:14 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libmagic-mgc armhf 1:5.35-4+deb10u1 [242 kB]
Get:15 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libmagic1 armhf 1:5.35-4+deb10u1 [110 kB]
Get:16 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf file armhf 1:5.35-4+deb10u1 [65.4 kB]
Get:17 http://mirror.as43289.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf xz-utils armhf 5.2.4-1 [179 kB]
Fetched 4,560 kB in 21s (219 kB/s)
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 29%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 59%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 89%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 0:
 newline in field name '▒PNG'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

i used this codes in the beginning. but for each one i got same error that error code (2)

```html
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python
```

i'm using Raspberry pi 1 version. it's old version i know but i have to use this.
Please help me guys. Thank all of you.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

It will fail when upgrading. Because this command is updating sources.list again. Because of this, it shows this error. You can run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` again. It's ok.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have the host properly set on the `/etc/hosts` file. In order to fix it, you should add raspberry to this same file. You can do so by making `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and adding this username next to the one you already have after the 127.0.1.1 address. Not after the word `localhost` (most surely you will have to edit the second line).

Comment: I guess you mean I need to enter this "sudo nano /etc/hosts" code into the console

Comment: yes, and once you are editting you may need to put "raspberry" (without the quotes) after the username that is already there. The one after 127.0.1.1 address

Comment: i'm using ssh for connection. when i input this code i get some svg code and i don't find user name and address that you gave me

Comment: aren't you capable of editing /etc/hosts?

Comment: I'm trying to connect with normally

Comment: It seems there is a problem with your kernel (which has nothing to do with the solution of before), you should try to load another, rebuild it or perhaps make a new fresh install